# Index of each occurrence of word in sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find index of each occurrence of word "dear" as it appear in following sentence. Can this be done via RegEx? If so how?

> Hello DEAR Friend, This is a string that contains repeititons of word dear; so my dear if you can tell me where each dear is located in the sentence, it will be great

Comment: Would you want to find the word 'dear' if it exists inside other words such as 'endearing' or 'dearly' or 'dearth'? Otherwise, the current answers would need to be modified to ensure that the the word is surrounded by a non-alpha characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(mystring, "dear", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
   Debug.Writeline(m.Index);
}
```

This is index of the character where it starts, if that's what you mean.

Comment: This won't match the first occurrence in his example will it?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
        string sentence = "Hello DEAR Friend, This is a string that contains repeititons of word dear; so my dear if you can keep count of word dear used, it will be great";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\bdear\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        foreach (Match m in r.Matches(sentence))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(m.Index.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: @Navigate: how will it give me the index of each occurance?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        Regex r = new Regex("dear",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string target = "Hello DEAR Friend, This is a string that contains repeititons of word dear; so my dear if you can tell me where each dear is located in the sentence, it will be great";
        MatchCollection allMatches = r.Matches(target);
```

Each `Match` object in `allMatches` will have the index of where it matched.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need Regular Expressions, as much as I love them, this solution is easier:

```
int index = yourString.IndexOf("dear", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
while(index > -1)
{
    // Do whatever with the index here
    index = yourString.IndexOf("dear", index + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is using list comprehension like so:

```
string1 = "This is the first airplane that flies around the world in far less time than the people thought"
print [i for i, j in enumerate(string1.split()) if j == 'the']
```

The above code finds all the occurrences of the word "the". The split() function splits the sentence into words.